# Does this question (about diff tools) belong on SFSE

Tags: discussion

[Recommendation on great Code Comparing Tools](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305/recommendation-on-great-code-comparing-tools)

It is my opinion that it doesn't belong on meta, but the point of meta is that everything that doesn't belong on [SFSE](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311/sfse-salesforce-stack-exchange) belongs on meta :)

This post has another purpose, which has been raised before, the perception that SFSE is a code only forum. One I would really like to change (although I don't know how)

Answer (score 5):

Yep, agreed, it's a totally appropriate question for the main site. The only potential knock on it could be that it's not Salesforce-centric enough, since a diff tool isn't a Salesforce need per se, but since it touches on deployment and the Force.com IDE includes a diff capability, I think it's totally appropriate.

Comment: Probably best on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: I think it's totally appropriate on our main site. Yes diff tools are general-purpose, but there is one built-in to the Force.com IDE, and it's a need that many SFDC folks have experienced for the first time, and there are considerations in the Force world that are unique (e.g. in the Force.com IDE diff, when you hit save, it saves back to the server).

Answer (score 5):

> the point of meta is that everything that doesn't belong on SFSE
>   belongs on meta :)

The way I understand it is that I'm now typing on "meta-Salesforce StackExchange", not on "meta-Salesforce".

We should discuss here some moderation policies, solve issues with tags etc. And main site should be for discussing and solving problems around actual Salesforce. Regardless how "meta" these problems may seem ;)

From programmers.stackexchange.com sidebar:

> Got a question about the site itself? meta is the place to talk about
>   things like what questions are appropriate, what tags we should use,
>   etc.

It's a very open ended question that probably should be marked as community wiki (there's no "one correct answer", right?) Not to mention the fact that for example in my workflow diffs are all nice and shiny but WinMerge excels when plugged into TortoiseSVN - answer like that kind of derails the topic.

I'd expect stuff like that either on main site or on StackOverflow itself. Would gain much more visibility, maybe there's an amazing tool we're not aware of because we're mostly focused on Eclipse...

[Programmers SE might not appreciate the "traffic" from us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl) ;)

Last quote, I promise ;)

https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

> We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in
>   them, but if your question generally covers …
>
> ```
> a specific programming problem
> a software algorithm
> software tools commonly used by programmers /* this */
> practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession
> ```
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!